# Media query issue: resizing/moving blocks

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to have three different layouts 
Desktop- image + text block on top of a page
Medium devices- image on top of a page and text on the bottom of the page
Mobile- text on the bottom of the page

I have figured out how I want to do the desktop and the mobile, and I thought I had the medium devices figured out, but it isn't working correctly.

HTML

```html
<div class="some-container--top">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="column image">
         <img src="{image url}" alt="alt" />
       </div>

    <div class=" column container">
       <img src="{image url}" alt="color" />
       <div class="text-block"> 
          <h3>title</h3>
          <p>text</p>
       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="some-container--bottom">
<p>text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
.some-container--bottom{
display:none;
}
}

@media only screen and(max-width:999px) and (min-width:601px){
.container{
display:none;
}
.some-container--bottom{
display:none;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
 .some-container--top{
 display:none;
}
}
```

So, desktop works (i.e, I have the picture and the text showing up correctly) and mobile works ( I have the text showing up where I want). However, for my medium devices it shows everything( text and image on both bottom and top of page). What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your css-rule:

```
@media only screen and(max-width:999px) and (min-width:601px){
                      ^ There must be a space between 'and' and the opening parenthesis
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wqrbc980/)

Comment: Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes. Thank you so much!

Comment: Morgan, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so you know how this site works. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.